# Чтение данных с COM порта в данный момент времени

Tags: c#, uart

Передаю раз в секунду по UART на COM-порт компьютера числа от 0 до 254 по возрастанию.
По нажатию кнопки в программе на C# на компьютере в label выводится прочитанное из COM-порта значение.

```
int b8;
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b8 = serialPort1.ReadByte();
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(b8);
    }
```

Но при нажатии кнопки button в label выводятся также числа по возрастанию (1, 2, 3, 4, 5...), хоть если нажать button не через секунду, а например через час. А мне надо выводить label последнее значение, пришедшее на COM-порт, как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно читать из порта данные постоянно (там очередь) и хранить последнее прочитанное число, а по нажатию кнопки - выводить его.